# How to move chemical structure from one to another file in ms word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word

I need to move Chemical structure from a file to another in ms word 2016. I want the structures to be moved together properly. And the structure can't break[ ][1]. How do I do this? [Image is attached here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSb7r.png

Comment: Select, copy, paste?  What have you tried? What problems? https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How is the structure built in the original document? Can you just screenshot it, or does it need to be modifiable in the new document?